# PHP Need nested array values to dump into html table cell

Tags: php, arrays, nested, stdclass

I have a stdClass Object array with nested User arrays as a value that I would like to display in a table cell.

I am struggling and have exhausted a lot of time. I am hoping to get a shove in the right direction if possible.

The image below will show what I am trying to do.

```
$someArray = json_decode($token_result);

foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    $combined[] =
        "<tr><td>" .
        $value->customer .
        "</td><td>" .
        $value->city .
        '</td>
           <td>' .
        $value->state .
        "</td><td>" .
        $value->zipcode .
        '</td>
           <td>' .
        $value->totalUsers .
        "</td><td>" .
        $value->totalActiveUsers .
        "</td><td>" .
        $value->totalInActiveUsers .
        '</td><td>
           <a href="">' .
        $value->users .
        "</a></td></tr>";
}

foreach ($combined as $value) {
    print $value;
}
```

Here is what my Array and Objects look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [customer] => SWSH
            [city] => Thomasville
            [state] => GA
            [zipcode] => 31792
            [totalUsers] => 6
            [totalActiveUsers] => 6
            [totalInActiveUsers] => 0
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [firstName] => xxx
                            [lastName] => xxx
                            [phoneNumber] => 
                            [userName] => cb_igwrth@xxx.com
                            [createdBy] => 
                            [isActive] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [firstName] => Dan
                            [lastName] => Stewart
                            [phoneNumber] => +11111111111
                            [userName] => dan.sxx@xxx.ga.gov
                            [createdBy] => kwilliams@xxx.com
                            [isActive] => 1
                        )
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [customer] => xxxx
            [city] => Carver
            [state] => MA
            [zipcode] => 02330
            [totalUsers] => 3
            [totalActiveUsers] => 3
            [totalInActiveUsers] => 0
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [firstName] => Leo
                            [lastName] => Furtado
                            [phoneNumber] => 781-000-0000
                            [userName] => LFurtado@xxx.com
                            [createdBy] => TConger@ccccc.com
                            [isActive] => 1
                        )                

                )

        )
)
```

Table Looks like this

[image]

Comment: What do you want to see in the User Data column? You're not doing anything to show the contents of those arrays.

Comment: For now Id like to see all stdClass Object Keys & Values for each user in a single cell...  I plan to take that data and display it in a Bootstrap Modal afterwords.  But for now just getting a dump of the data in to the cell is the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to create the markup for the individual users. It would probably make your life easier to create functions for building the outer rows and the individual user details.

```php
<?php
$token_result = <<<END
[
  {
    "customer": "SWSH",
    "city": "Thomasville",
    "state": "GA",
    "zipcode": "31792",
    "totalUsers": 6,
    "totalActiveUsers": 6,
    "totalInActiveUsers": 0,
    "users": [
      {
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "phoneNumber": "555-5555",
        "userName": "cb_igwrth@xxx.com",
        "createdBy": "someone",
        "isActive": 1
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Dan",
        "lastName": "Stewart",
        "phoneNumber": "+11111111111",
        "userName": "dan.sxx@xxx.ga.gov",
        "createdBy": "kwilliams@xxx.com",
        "isActive": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "customer": "xxxx",
    "city": "Carver",
    "state": "MA",
    "zipcode": "02330",
    "totalUsers": 3,
    "totalActiveUsers": 3,
    "totalInActiveUsers": 0,
    "users": [
      {
        "firstName": "Leo",
        "lastName": "Furtado",
        "phoneNumber": "781-000-0000",
        "userName": "LFurtado@xxx.com",
        "createdBy": "TConger@ccccc.com",
        "isActive": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
END;



$someArray = json_decode($token_result);

function buildRowMarkupFromValue($value)
{
    $userDetails = implode('', array_map('buildUserDetailMarkupFromUser', $value->users));

    return <<<END
<tr>
    <td>$value->customer</td>
    <td>$value->city</td>
    <td>$value->state</td>
    <td>$value->zipcode</td>
    <td>$value->totalUsers</td>
    <td>$value->totalActiveUsers</td>
    <td>$value->totalInActiveUsers</td>
    <td>
        $userDetails
    </td>
</tr>

END;
}

function buildUserDetailMarkupFromUser($user)
{
    $activeIndicator = ($user->isActive) ? 'Active':'Inactive';

    return <<<END
$user->firstName $user->lastName (<a href="mailto:$user->userName">$user->userName</a>)<br>
<a href="tel:$user->phoneNumber">$user->phoneNumber</a><br>
Created by <a href="mailto:$user->createdBy">$user->createdBy</a><br>
$activeIndicator<br>
<br>
END;

}

$combined = array_map('buildRowMarkupFromValue', $someArray);

foreach ($combined as $value) {
    print $value;
}
```

Eventually it would be better to come up with a way of separating your templates and code, this is pretty ugly.

Comment: This did the trick- I was able to add a link to launch a bootstrap modals from each table cell with the correct data in it with in just a few minutes. :)